# A die is rolled five times, what is the probability that exactly two results are ones, and exactly three are sixes?

Tags: probability

I've solved it this way: if a die is rolled 5 times, there are 6<sup>5</sup> = 7776 total variants. We can find how many variants satisfy condition  using formula of permutations with repetition (three of one kind, and two of the other): $\frac{5!}{3! * 2!}= 10$, so the answer seems to be $\frac{10}{7776} ≈ 0.001286$. Is it right? I think there should be more general approach to that sort of problems, but I'm not sure which exactly.

Comment: Yes, that 's correct.  Seems like a pretty general approach to me!

Comment: @lulu: Is it not $$\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}}{6^5} \, ?$$

Comment: If the die was not fair you would also need the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: @Joe Did you mean $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{3}}{6^5}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Yes, that's what I meant. I'm not used to typesetting these things...

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I think I worked out my mistake, anyway. The problem boils down to finding the number of ways you can choose $2$ ones and $3$ sixes. If you imagine placing the ones and sixes sequentially, then at first you have $5$ options to place a one, then $4$ options to place another one. That gives us $20$ combinations, but we have to divide by $2$ to remove duplicates. Once we have done that, there is only one way in which the remaining sixes can be placed, and so that's it.

Comment: @Joe that's how I imagined it too! By the way, what would I do if a die has been rolled more times than quantity of dice involved in conditions, let's say 10, so that problem couldn't boil down to permutations? That's what I meant by general approach

Comment: @wanderbild Welcome to MSE.  Please don't ask new questions in comments.  Simply post another question.  The goal of the site is to build up a fund of questions and answers, so that people can search for the answers to their questions.  Comments aren't searchable, so asking questions here defeats the purpose.  (And try to see if someone has asked the question before.  I'd bet on it.)

Comment: @wanderbild: I would suggest asking that as a new question (or look to see if it has been asked before, as saulpatz mentions). There are people who are more qualified than me who can give you an answer.